# Solr DIH error while importing data from hive

Tags: hadoop, solr, hive, dih

I am trying to load and index hdfs data in solr 5.1.I stored the data in a  hive table and used DIH to import and index. i followed the steps provided in the link [Solr DIH](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_RDBMS). I couldn't see any material on DIH with hive so Wanted to check if anyone have worked on this . Also looking for some suggestions on the above scenario.

Comment: I am looking for a simillar solution, did you got any progress.

Comment: Nope for DIH. I stored the data in HDFS and proceeded

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get it working.
It is very interesting how it worked.

We got the hive2 jars first and made it working on through java to check the connectivity.
Then we realized the jars to be used are :

1. hadoop-common-2.7.0-mapr-1703.jar
2. hive-common-2.1.1-mapr-1703-r1.jar
3. hive-jdbc-2.1.1-mapr-1703-r1-standalone.jar

If you are using SOLR Cloud then these jars are to be transferred to the VM where SOLR is installed and then referenced in solrconfig.xml like this:

### Import Part in solrconfig.xml

< lib dir="/users/path_to_folder_with_jar" regex=".*.jar" />

Then this is the most important part: Your hive connection string:

### Connection Part

< dataConfig >
< dataSource name="ABC" driver="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" url="jdbc:hive2://....connectionString" user="username" password="password" />

< document name="collection_name">

< entity name="collection_lookup" query="select unique_key as id from table_name">

< /entity>

< /document>

< /dataConfig>

### Push config through zookeeper

server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost host1:2181,host2:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname configName -confdir server/solr/configsets/folder/

Go to http://host:8983/solr/#/collection_name/dataimport//dataimport
then check debug and first check with 10 or 20 records.

You will see the data flowing. CHEERS !!
I can help if you want to discuss further but I am assuming this should do. It is working for me.

Special thanks to Srini Samudrala for working with me on this.